# node.js ECONNRESET error after a while idle

Tags: node.js, postgresql, server, timeout

I'm using node.js and PostgreSQL as my database. I use the below code to connect my database.

```
 const pool = new pg.Pool(config);
pool.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected to database', config.database);
});
```

and this is the config codes:

```
const crypto = require('crypto').randomBytes(256).toString('hex');
module.exports = {
    host:'192.168.87.8',
    user: 'fjavadpour',
    database: 'fj_correspondence',
    password: 'Fariba321',
    port: 5432,
    max: 200,
    secret:crypto,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 72000000
};
```

but my database connection will crash and stop after being idle about one hour.
how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your host? Is it within the same network?

Comment: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1344#issuecomment-365563983 ?..

Comment: @AnshulVerma yes! I can connect to the host at first but it crashes and get ECONNRESET error when I don't contact to the database after about an hour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try adding `keepAlive:true` to your config and then check?